# Heads up on implementing rowsorter and rowfilter java 1.4

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Could anyone please give me a heads-up on how to implement my own row filter and row sorter to apply on a Jtable, while keeping in mind that I'm using Java 1.4? Or if there are some available classes that would serve that purpose?

Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Philip Milne's `TableSorter` & `TableMap` classes, <strike>discussed</strike> archived [here](http://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/cps108/spring04/code/jtable/code.ps) and [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableSorterDemoProject/src/components/TableSorter.java). A complete example in included in `/demo/jfc/TableExample` among the [*Java SE Development Kit 8u65 Demos and Samples*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

The `TableSorterDemo` constructor shows how to use the classes.

```
public TableSorterDemo() { 
    super(new GridLayout(1,0)); 
    TableSorter sorter = new TableSorter(new MyTableModel()); //ADDED THIS 
    //JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());          //OLD 
    JTable table = new JTable(sorter);             //NEW 
    sorter.addMouseListenerToHeaderInTable(table); //ADDED THIS 
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ah, _tempus fugit_ —[P. Vergilius Maro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempus_fugit).

Comment: Sorry for sounding a bit stupid, but how can I make use of the TableSorter class? I made an instance of it, and I passed my own TableModel to it that extends AbstractTableModel, but from there on I didn't know what to do?

Comment: The [`TableSorterDemo`](http://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/cps108/spring04/code/jtable/code.ps) constructor is a good example.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies everyone, I really appreciate it.
I have to deliver a design review in three hours, and I should be done with this issue!

The TableSorter.java class that was provided in here doesn't contain a method called  addMouseListenerToHeaderInTable. The version of TableSorter is 2.0 as the header of the file suggests. How can I use it to add the mouse listener?

Comment: Oh it's working now! all I did was to provide the header to the sorter and it worked liked a charm!
What about an alternative to RowFilter in Java 6? Is there a ready class that does exactly the same, but using Java 1.4?  I really appreciate the help guys.

Comment: I see `addMouseListenerToHeaderInTable()` on [page 5/5](http://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/cps108/spring04/code/jtable/code.ps), but the later version appears to listen automatically.

Comment: I'm not aware of a `RowFilter` back-port.

Answer (score 2):

Consider to use GlazedLists

http://www.glazedlists.com/Home

they still maintain a version for 1.4