# TableSorter numeric values sorting

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablesorter, comparator

Since I'm using Java 1.4.2, this means that I cannot use Java's implementation of the table sorter. Instead, I've been using the TableSorter.java class from an earlier reply to my previous post:
[Heads up on implementing rowsorter and rowfilter java 1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798411/heads-up-on-implementing-rowsorter-and-rowfilter-java-1-4)

It's working perfectly with one problem however, which is that it doesn't sort numeric values correctly. For instance, I have the following sequence of numbers in my table:
5,18,9,7,2,33

A increasing order sorting would display them like this in my JTable:

18,2,33,5,7,9

A decreasing order sorting would display them like this in my JTable:
9,7,5,33,2,18

I don't know if you have realized it, but apparently, the sorting of numeric values is only happening based on the first digit.

Do you have any quick fix for the problem? Please bare in mind that those numeric values are used as strings in my JTable as suggested by the getValue() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update you guys on this, what I did was to replace the LEXICAL_COMPARATOR in the TableSorter.java from my original post with this:

`public static final Comparator LEXICAL_COMPARATOR = new Comparator() {
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            if(o1 instanceof Integer)
            {

                Integer firstNumeric, secondNumeric;`

```
            firstNumeric =(Integer)o1;
            secondNumeric= (Integer)o2;

                    return firstNumeric.compareTo(secondNumeric);


        }
        else
        return o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString());
    }
};
```

Now, in the getValueAt, make sure that your "int" values are cast into Integer by simply doing:
`new Integer(intValue);`

I hope this will save people some time.

Answer (score 2):

Verify that `getColumnClass()` returns a numeric type, such as `Number`.

Addendum: [`MyTableModel`](http://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/cps108/spring04/code/jtable/code.ps) in `TableSorterDemo` is an example. Data for the third column is of type `Integer`, a subclass of `Number`; as a result, `getColumnClass()` returns `Integer.class`. Because `Integer` implements `Comparable`, the column is sorted numerically.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a `Comparator` that performs a numeric comparison rather than the default lexicographical one. So something like (taken from http://crossedlogic.blogspot.com/2008/11/java-custom-comparators-sorting-text.html):

```
Comparator c1 = new java.util.Comparator() {
        /**
         * Custom compare to sort numbers as numbers.
         * Strings as strings, with numbers ordered before strings.
         * 
         * @param o1
         * @param o2
         * @return
         */
@Override
            public int compare(Object oo1, Object oo2) {
                boolean isFirstNumeric, isSecondNumeric;
                String o1 = oo1.toString(), o2 = oo2.toString();


            isFirstNumeric = o1.matches("\\d+");
            isSecondNumeric = o2.matches("\\d+");

            if (isFirstNumeric) {
                if (isSecondNumeric) {
                    return Integer.valueOf(o1).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o2));
                } else {
                    return -1; // numbers always smaller than letters
                }
            } else {
                if (isSecondNumeric) {
                    return 1; // numbers always smaller than letters
                } else {
                    isFirstNumeric = o1.split("[^0-9]")[0].matches("\\d+");
                    isSecondNumeric = o2.split("[^0-9]")[0].matches("\\d+");

                    if (isFirstNumeric) {
                        if (isSecondNumeric) {
                            int intCompare = Integer.valueOf(o1.split("[^0-9]")[0]).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o2.split("[^0-9]")[0]));
                            if (intCompare == 0) {
                                return o1.compareToIgnoreCase(o2);
                            }
                            return intCompare;
                        } else {
                            return -1; // numbers always smaller than letters
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (isSecondNumeric) {
                            return 1; // numbers always smaller than letters
                        } else {
                            return o1.compareToIgnoreCase(o2);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

then pass that in as the comparator for the column:

```
tblSorter.setColumnComparator(String.class, c1);
```

Let me know how that works.

Comment: You can also use Apache commons' number utils [NumberUtils.isNumber(o1)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html#isNumber(java.lang.String)) if you are in to that kind of thing like me.

Comment: Femi thanks for the quick reply mate.
So how can I add this to the TableSorter in the post that I have mentioned before? I would really need a heads up on this..

Comment: Btw Femi, the code that you have provided only works with Java 1.5+. I'm restricted to using java 1.4.2...

Comment: Odd. Wasn't aware I had any 1.5 syntax statements in there. What compile errors do you get?

Comment: I'm not getting compiler errors, but some parsing errors in Eclipse mainly this: Comparator<String>
Parametrized types are only available if source level is 1.5.

I really need help  in this man, so I would appreciate it if anyone would help me. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Ah. You can just remove the String parameter. I've edited the block of code.

Comment: Femi, it didn't work :( I'm still getting the same results as before although I did exactly what you suggested.. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Btw, in the tablemodel's getValueAt method, this is how I'm getting the quantity column:

else if (colNames[columnIndex].equals(COL_NAME_QUANTITY))
   return Integer.toString(((LogEntry)logList.get(rowIndex)).getQuantity());

Would that have anything to do with my wrong results?

Comment: I modified the class to take in `Object`s, rather than `String`s. The `getValueAt` method sounds right: it really should sort properly now. Are you setting the Comparator for the right column (COL_NAME_QUANTITY)? I'm guessing it isn't correctly using the new Comparator.

Comment: Oh! I probably misunderstood something! how can I set the comparator for a specific column?

Comment: My quantity column is the 5th column in my JTable, how can I set the comparator to that specific column Femi?

Comment: The `TableSorter` class has a `getComparator(int column)` method unless I'm wrong: you'll need to override it to return the special comparator for COL_NAME_QUANTITY.

Comment: Yes you're right, the TableSorter class has a getComparator(int column) method. This is the method:
  protected Comparator getComparator(int column) {
        Class columnType = tableModel.getColumnClass(column);
        Comparator comparator = (Comparator) columnComparators.get(columnType);
        if (comparator != null) {
            return comparator;
        }
        if (Comparable.class.isAssignableFrom(columnType)) {
            return COMPARABLE_COMAPRATOR;
        }
        return LEXICAL_COMPARATOR;
    }

What would I exactly do? Thanks a lot Fermi.