# JTable Sorting based on hidden column

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable, tablerowsorter

I would like to sort `JTable` rows based on one hidden column.

Say I have a JTable like this

```
column1   column2
val1       val2
```

Now I have a one more column3 which is hidden and I dont want to show. When user clicks on Column2 it should sort rows based on Column3 (hidden column) not based Column2.

How to achieve this in JTable?

Comment: on a quest to confuse your users ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add by default [TableRowSorter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableRowSorter.html) to [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) but there is [RowSorter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/RowSorter.html), nothing better and clear around as Darryl's [Multisort Table Header Cell Renderer](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/08/29/multisort-table-header-cell-renderer/)

note definitions for RowSorter is valid only for concrete TableColumn

siple example (with use-less balast again)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class HeaderDoubleclickTest {

    private String[] columnNames = {"String", "Integer", "Boolean"};
    private Object[][] data = {
        {"aaa", 12, true}, {"bbb", 5, false},
        {"CCC", 92, true}, {"DDD", 0, false}
    };
    private TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
            return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
        }
    };
    private JTable table = new JTable(model);
    private JTableHeader header;

    static class TestTableRowSorter extends TableRowSorter<TableModel> {

        TestTableRowSorter(TableModel m) {
            super(m);
        }

        @Override
        public void toggleSortOrder(int column) {
        }

        public void wrapToggleSortOrder(int column) {
            super.toggleSortOrder(column);
        }
    }
    private Timer timer = new Timer(400, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("single");
            JTable table = header.getTable();
            RowSorter sorter;
            if (pt != null && table != null && (sorter = table.getRowSorter()) != null) {
                int columnIndex = header.columnAtPoint(pt);
                if (columnIndex != -1) {
                    columnIndex = table.convertColumnIndexToModel(columnIndex);
                    ((TestTableRowSorter) sorter).wrapToggleSortOrder(columnIndex);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    private Point pt;

    public JComponent makeUI() {
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        table.setRowSorter(new TestTableRowSorter(model));
        header = table.getTableHeader();
        header.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(final MouseEvent e) {
                if (timer.isRunning() && !e.isConsumed() && e.getClickCount() > 1) {
                    System.out.println("double");
                    pt = null;
                    timer.stop();
                } else {
                    pt = e.getPoint();
                    timer.restart();
                }
            }
        });
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        p.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        return p;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(new HeaderDoubleclickTest().makeUI());
        f.setSize(320, 240);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to pass hiddlen column index to wrapToggleSortOrder(int column)? Will it sort based on hidden column?

Comment: @Umesh: This is a good example of intercepting header clicks and distinguishing between single and double clicks, should you also need that functionality; but it doesn't address the sort order directly. See also this [complementary approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937694/jtable-sorting-based-on-hidden-column/6939889#6939889). +1 for [Alpha Icons](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/08/22/alpha-icons/).

Answer (score 3):

Use code posted here: http://www.esus.com/docs/GetQuestionPage.jsp?uid=1270

there's variable / method argument `col` - just check if its yours column2 and if so treat it like it was your hidden column - sort by it and rerender table.

Comment: +1 This might be useful for supporting older versions; see also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798411/heads-up-on-implementing-rowsorter-and-rowfilter-java-1-4/5798542#5798542).

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to implement the [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface for the type `Column2`, as shown in this [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table), and compare using the corresponding `Column3` value. Conveniently, if `Column3` already implements `Comparable<Column3>`, you can just delegate to `Column3`, as the [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table) does with `Double`.