# How to setRowSorter for custom tablemodel?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel, tablerowsorter

I have defined a custom tablemodel like the following

```
  class TModel extends AbstractTableModel {

  Object col[] = null;
  Object[][] data = null;
  
  public void setCollen(Object[] col) {
    this.col = col;
  }

  public void setObj(Object[][] oo) {
    this.data = oo;
  }

  public int getColumnCount() {
    return col.length;
  }

  public int getRowCount() {
    return data.length;
  }

  public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
    return data[row][col];
  }

  public String getColumnName(int column) {
    return (String) col[column];
  }

  public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
    return false;
  }

  public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column) {
    data[row][column] = aValue;
  }

  public void clear() {
    data = null;
  }
}
```

And I defined a table like this

```
TModel tableModel = new TModel();
JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
```

Now I want to use the method `table.setRowSorter()` to sort the data of the table.

I tried to write code like this

```
     table.setRowSorter(new TableRowSorter(tableModel));
```

Obviously it is wrong.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 3):

1. your `AbstractTableModel` is wrong, isn't completed, missing there important notifiers f.e. `fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);` in `setValueAt`, e.i. ....
2. [for proper sorting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) to [override `ColumnClass`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232432/sorting-rows-by-columns-in-jtable/6233119#6233119)
3. for basic sorting funcionalities you can to define `table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true)` only
4. read [Oracles tutorial  about Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)
5. I'd to suggest use `DefaultTableModel`, for data stucture based on `Object[][]` or `Vector<Vector>`, there no needed to override are all notifiers implemented and correctly
6. [code example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937694/jtable-sorting-based-on-hidden-column/6938025#6938025)