# Java sort JTable rows

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable, permutation

I am trying to order table rows by permutation for example (6 7 3 9 5 1 4 2 8).
Basic order of JTable can be took as a permutation of (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9).

my code is

```
        for(int j = 0; j < model.getRowCount(); j++){
                swapRows(model, j, permutation[j] - 1);
        }
```

swap function

```
private void swapRows(DefaultTableModel model, int i, int j){
    System.out.println( i + " " + j );
    if(i < j){
        model.moveRow(i, i, j);
        model.moveRow(j - 1, j - 1, i);
    }else if( i > j){
        model.moveRow(i, i, j);
        model.moveRow(j + 1, j + 1, i);
    }

}
```

but the table is not sorted as i want (6 7 3 9 5 1 4 2 8)

Comment: Do you need to order by permutation or only to order?

Comment: order by permutation as i wrote

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5798411/230513), which shows how to map row indexes.